# Entity Framework v5 loading relational data

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have two very simple POCO that i want to connect through a one to many relation

```
public class Menu
{
    public int MenuId { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MenuMember> MenuMembers { get; set; }
}

public  class MenuMember
{
    public int MenuMemberId { get; set; }
    public int MenuId { get; set; }
    public string  ViewRoute { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive{ get; set; }
}

public  class EFDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Page> Pages { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Menu > Menus { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MenuMember> MenuMembers{ get; set; }
}
```

Now what I have to do is very simple , but I all the resources on the internet are suprisingly so vague (or i am too dumb)

I want to write an lambda expression for

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM Menu INNER JOIN MenuMembers 
    ON Menu.MenuId = MenuMembers.MenuId 
WHERE Menu.MenuId = 1
```

I have used this

```
IEnumerable<Menu> menu 
    = repository.Menus.Where(x => x.MenuId == menuId);
```

but when I iterate over it, `menu.MenuNumbers` stays null. I believe it is some sort of lazyloading issue.

Comment: What result do you get with this statement? IEnumerable<Menu> menu 
    = repository.Menus.ToList():

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either `Include()` the relation manually for eager loading:

> [Entity Framework Loading Related Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj574232):
>
> Eager loading is the process whereby a query for one type of entity also loads related entities as part of the query. Eager loading is achieved by use of the **Include** method.

```
IEnumerable<Menu> menu = repository.Menus
                                   .Include(m => m.MenuMembers)
                                   .Where(x => x.MenuId == menuId);
```

Or mark the property as `virtual` so Entity Framework will lazy-load it:

> Lazy loading is the process whereby an entity or collection of entities is automatically loaded from the database the first time that a property referring to the entity/entities is accessed. When using POCO entity types, lazy loading is achieved by creating instances of derived proxy types and then overriding **virtual** properties to add the loading hook.

```
public class Menu
{
    public int MenuId { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MenuMember> MenuMembers { get; set; }
}
```

And there's a few other options, be sure to [check out the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj574232).

Comment: Thanks for the response . I used the include way and I got data from both the tables . I used nested foreach to print the data out . However now this leads to another problem . . How would i use an order by clause with a field of the second table ? .

Comment: because in the lambda expression , we can use a field of the Menu class , but we can't use a field of the MenuMember class in an orderby extension right ? . Is there any work around here

Comment: @MuhammadAhmedAbuTalib you can just `OrderBy(m => m.MenuMembers.SomeAggregateFunction())`, but you'll have to use an aggregate function because you cannot order "by collection" as that is not a thing. You'll have to calculate an aggregate over each collection to sort by. You can for example order by the amount of members: `OrderBy(m => m.MenuMembers.Count())`, but not by a single field of `MenuMembers`. Anyway that is a totally unrelated question, so if you can't figure it out please ask a new one, showing what you have tried.

Comment: You are right CodeCaster, sorting is unrelated. Thanks for your help regarding the join .

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `MenuMembers` as `virtual`

```
public virtual ICollection<MenuMember> MenuMembers { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks Le , I did as you mention above and ran across another error . I used a nested foreach to obtain the data from the second table .  foreach (var item in menuItems)
            {
                foreach (MenuMember mm in item.MenuMembers )
                {
                    Console.Write(mm.ViewRoute);
                }
            }

Comment: when the control would reach to the second foreach , it would throw an exception stating that "A previous datareader was already open and needs to be closed" . I think i am doing some mistake here ?